# How to concatenate 3 columns into one in a Matlab Table?

Tags: matlab, datetime

I have a Matlab table with three columns: Year, Month, Day.
I want to make it into one column that represents the date in a format `'MM/dd/yyyy'`. How can I do that? I tried quite a while to no avail, but I believe someone may know it immediately.

Comment: Please include a portion of your code where you think the problem is.

Comment: Check please datenum function(http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html)

Comment: I don't have a code smipet for this yet since I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a table with three columns with your values. As your table must contain the same type of data, you must first make sure that your values for the month, day and year are in the string format. If they aren't, convert them into strings (use B(:,1)=int2str(A(:,1)) for example)

Once your data in the string table, concatenate them in a 4th column.

```
for i=1:length(B(:,1))
B(i,4)=strcat(B(i,1), "/", B(i,2), "/", B(i,3));
end
```

Comment: Thank you. But the length is giving error message saying that "Undefined function 'length' for input arguments of type 'table'.  Use the HEIGHT, WIDTH, or SIZE
functions instead."

Comment: I edited my answer, it should work now ( Replaced A(:), which does not represent a column, by A(:,1), which represents the first column, so it could be used with `length`.

Comment: Thanks. I got this error: "Error using strcat (line 82)
You can not subscript a table using only one subscript. Table subscripting requires both row and
variable subscripts."

Comment: Are you sure you have the right format for your data before trying to use this code sample ? If so, i'm afraid i don't see where i blundered,.. Oh, and i forgot to replace A by B in the code, i just edited that, mcheck your data or see if this (finally) works.

Comment: Got this error: Error: The input character is not valid in MATLAB statements or expressions.

Comment: After I changed " to ', I got this: Error using table/length (line 394)
Undefined function 'length' for input arguments of type 'table'.  Use the HEIGHT, WIDTH, or
SIZE functions instead.  My B is a table read from an excel test file which has 3 columns and 10 rows, with columns: Year, Month, Day.

Comment: Is your month column string or number?